# Can a Wii-U gamepad be used as the screen for multiple players?

Tags: controllers, wii-u

The Wii U is of interest to me due to the fact you do not necessarily need a TV in order to use it, being able to use the game pad as the screen.However, I would mainly be interested in playing with another individual.

Since the Wii U does not allow multiple game pads, is it possible to have two players using the game pad purely as the screen, with Wii remotes being used as the controllers?

Comment: I made an edit to your post to remove the two other questions. Generally, you want to post a single question at a time, on Arqade. You are more then welcome to post multiple questions, but in each question itself, keep it to the one. Probably wouldn't have been an issue in this context, but don't ask if a developer is going to include a feature, later, as we can't really tell you without speculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but depends on the game. Basically, if you can play multiplayer with just the TV, you can play multiplayer with just the gamepad screen.

For example, Mario Kart 8 just clones the TV output to the gamepad, so you can have multiple people play just looking at the gamepad's screen.
Hyrule Warriors doesn't have splitscreen option and each player gets its own screen, so you can't play co-op with just the gamepad.

If the game uses IR sensor, you still have to use the IR bar. Where you put it is your choice, but make sure you calibrate it if it's at a different distance/location than the TV that it's calibrated to.

Comment: How about another example, Splatoon?

Comment: Is proximity to the TV / console a requirement for motion? (I assume not, for general input, but I'm more familiar with the Wii which has sensors on the console.)

Comment: I don't own Splatoon, so I don't know how multiplayer works with it. Does it have splitscreen or each player uses their own screen?

Comment: @Timelord64 if the game uses IR sensor, you still have to use the IR bar. Where you put it is your choice, but make sure you calibrate it if it's at a different distance/location than the TV that it's calibrated to.

Comment: I have no idea, actually. I do not even own the console. Thank your for your reaponses though!

Comment: I looked up, it seems that you *have to* use the gamepad as a controller for player 1 in local multiplayer in Splatoon, so you wouldn't be able to play local multiplayer using the gamepad as the screen.

Comment: Asked, as I could see that being an issue, with some games. Added your response to the answer

Comment: @Timelord64 good thinking, I haven't played any games that uses the IR sensor in such a long time, I forgot it existed :P

Comment: Also looked up some gameplay footage of local multiplayer splatoon. each player has their own screen.